# Iterating over a csv reader object to call api with requests.get

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

I have several hundred companies to query with an api.
The api url call for each is in a csv file in one column in the form:
http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"Company Name"}&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I've used csv to open and read in the csv file as a reader object but I can't work out how to iterate over this to get the return details for each company e.g.

```
for row in reader:
  requests.get(row)
```

Running on a single url works fine giving the JSON data I'd expect:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

Apologies if this is a bit of a trivial seeming question but how can I simply iterate over each url in the csv reader object feeding it into a requests.get call and store the result in a file object of some sort.
Thanks

This is what the csv.reader object prints out as:

```
for row in reader:

print(row)

['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"Parkeon Ltd"}&api_key=xxxxxxx ']
['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"M and D Foundations and Building Services Ltd"}&api_key=xxxxxxxxx ']
['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"TM Lewin"}&api_key=xxxxxx ']
['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"Stralfors Plc"}&api_key=xxxxxx ']
['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"CPM UK Ltd"}&api_key=xxxxx ']
```

Comment: Can you show us how exactly your csv file looks like?

Comment: Store the results in a list? `l = []` `for row in reader: l.append(requests.get(row))`

Comment: Have shown how the csv file looks above.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV reader class returns a tuple, even when there's only one row. Try using:

```
for row in reader:
    requests.get(row[0])
```

Comment: for row in reader:
    requests.get(row[0]) seems to give me back the last element in the list as :

row

Out[75]:

['http://api.duedil.com/open/search?q={"Danone Romania"}&api_key=xxxxx']

Comment: Based on what you printed above, row[0] should work totally fine.